# How does EOS address its Smart Contracts?

Tags: smart-contract, hash

Ethereum (for comparison purposes only), uses the address of the creator, the nonce, which is keccak (does EOS use this type of hashing?) hashed with the senders address(roughly-  [see related question for ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed). Is this any different for EOS, how does EOS generate its smart contract addreses?

Answer (score 2):

EOSIO uses human-readable account names as blockchain identifiers, not hashed address.

Account names are chosen by the creator of each respective account, and it needs to have at most 12 characters (a-z, 1-5, or .). Internally, these are in fact interpreted as base32 string representations of `uint64` types.

Accounts may or may not have code associated with them, which defines whether transactions will interact with a smart contract or not.

[Relevant docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/accounts-1):

> An account is a collection of authorizations, stored on the
>   blockchain, and used to identify a sender/recipient. It has a flexible
>   authorization structure that enables it to be owned either by an
>   individual or group of individuals depending on how permissions have
>   been configured. An account is required to send or receive a valid
>   transaction to the blockchain

Comment: Accounts are human readable,  does EOS also address, Smart Contracts similarly, ie in  a human readable way? So does the trie management Iif used by EOS for contract addressing) and so on, in human readable form?

Comment: smart contracts are just accounts with code so they're addressed by the account name as well

Answer (score 0):

Here's some helpful documentation relating to how accounts are used on EOS. 
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/accounts-1